# Why my javascript program is not converting it to integer rather than string?

Tags: javascript

i have created a simple program in which it needs to add 1 and 3 and show 4 but it shows me 13 here is my program:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function calculate(){

            a = document.getElementById('num1').value;
            b = document.getElementById('num2').value;
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = a + b;
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id='num1' value="1"/>
        <input id='num2' value='3'/>
        <p id='result'></p>
        <button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

What do i do now?

Comment: It would be evident that your code is concatenating two variables rather than adding as intended. Concatenation is an operation performed on `string` objects, whereas addition is an operation performed on numeric objects. What do you think needs to happen for both `string` variables to treat them as numeric?

Comment: i recomend to declare your varibles after assigning a value, i mean: var a = ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `value` attribute returns a `String`. You need to convert it to a `Number`.

There's a shortcut though, by using `+` unary operator. You can also wrap the string in `Number` like `Number(a) + Number(b)`.

```
a = +document.getElementById('num1').value;
b = +document.getElementById('num2').value;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert to integer. Check out this code.

```
    function calculate(){

        a = parseInt(document.getElementById('num1').value, 10);
        b = parseInt(document.getElementById('num2').value, 10);
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = a + b;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =  parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
```

The reason is because you a and b are strings and you need first to convert then to numbers.

Comment: It's a bad idea to ignore the radix.